# How to find index of a list in dynamodb?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I am using Python's boto3 for Amazon's api and dynamodb.

I want to store id's of people who have liked a post. I am currently appending to that list when someone likes a post ( Each post has likedBy list ).
I am using `SET likedBy = list_append(likedBy, :v)` to add to the list when someone likes a post.
Ex:

```
"likedBy" : [
    {
      "on": 1455736397,
      "userId": 232323
    },
    {
      "on": 1455736398,
      "userId": 46
    }]
```

But how do i **remove that particular user from the list** when they unlike again? And also i want to ensure that one user can only like a post only once? ( **Ensure that userId in likedBy list is unique**)

One solution i could think of was to get the whole list and check if list has `userId`, then find index and use AWS updateexpression `REMOVE likedBy[index]` to remove. ( i know this is not the correct way )

Comment: what is your dynamodb hash/range keys?

Comment: hash key is the postId and i don't have a range key. I can access likedBy list using postId, but i want to manipulate list items with inner nested elements

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to use list indexes.

your table scheme should be:

```
hash_key=post_id
range_key=user_id
```

now, this will allow you to:

1. get all likes(user_ids) belongs to a post id
2. enforce uniqueness. (only one record for post_id - user_id)
3. delete a post_id belongs to user_id

Comment: i cannot have user_id as range key as a single user can create multiple posts. And i want to store list of people who liked a post in list ( this will be an attribute for that post )

Comment: why you cant  have user_id as range key? even if user can create multiple posts? if you need a list of people who liked a post then you can add global secondary index (hash:user_id, range:post_id). this is exactly the power of dynamodb, you dont need to use it on application level. it will allow you also to use pagination if you need.

Comment: yes, i understood your point. but i have comments and shares also. So do you suggest having 3 tables for maintaining likes, shares and comments ( seems good, but what if there are lot of posts and lot of likesv) or 1 table, with nested elements for likes, shares and comments ( uniqueness will be a probelm and deletion)

Comment: you should have 1 table with 3 global secondary indexes (hash/range) (one for like, one for comment, one for share).